# Array of Objects Optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, database

## Below I have a set of data I receive from a server.

I need to find from the data which "id" is connected to which "apip"

## I have working code below.

## My question is...did I do it in the most efficient way possible ?

My strategy was as follows:

Step 1 - Capture All the apip save them into an array

Step 2 - clear out all repeating apip

Step 3 - for loop to compare if apip matches apip

-If true capture that ID

-else store that ID on apip 2

(IT IS KNOW that I only have 2 possible APIPs)

Step 4 - clear out any repeating "ids"

Was this the best approach ?

```js
var data = [{
  "time": "1571965891.8420029",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "123456789",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.1"
}, {
  "time": "1571971066.8283374",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "100",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.2"
}, {
  "time": "1571965476.4821894",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "123456789",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.2"
}, {
  "time": "1571965894.140705",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "123456789",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.2"
}, {
  "time": "1571965893.1654441",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "123456789",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.1"
}, {
  "time": "1571970952.7499905",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "9999999",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.1"
}, {
  "time": "1571965888.1338017",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "123456789",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.2"
}, {
  "time": "1571970925.342063",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "66666",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.1"
}, {
  "time": "1571965890.158157",
  "rssi": "30",
  "id": "123456789",
  "apip": "172.172.172.172.1"
}]

console.log(data)

var APs = [];
var dataFromAP1 = [];
var dataFromAP2 = [];
data.forEach(item => {
  APs.push(item.apip);
});
console.log(APs);
var uniq = [...new Set(APs)];
console.log(uniq);

data.forEach(item => {
  if (item.apip === uniq[0]) {
    dataFromAP1.push(item.id);
  } else {
    dataFromAP2.push(item.id);
  }
});

var uniqdataFromAP1 = [...new Set(dataFromAP1)];
console.log(uniqdataFromAP1);

var uniqdataFromAP2 = [...new Set(dataFromAP2)];
console.log(uniqdataFromAP2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the one of the `uniq`s (let's call it `oneApip`), just check the first element of the `data` - you dont need a Set or to iterate over all of them. Then iterate over the `data` and, for each element, add to one set or the other, depending on whether its `apip` matches that `oneApip`:

```js
var data=[{time:"1571965891.8420029",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"},{time:"1571971066.8283374",rssi:"30",id:"100",apip:"172.172.172.172.2"},{time:"1571965476.4821894",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.2"},{time:"1571965894.140705",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.2"},{time:"1571965893.1654441",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"},{time:"1571970952.7499905",rssi:"30",id:"9999999",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"},{time:"1571965888.1338017",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.2"},{time:"1571970925.342063",rssi:"30",id:"66666",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"},{time:"1571965890.158157",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"}];

const oneApip = data[0].apip;
const set1 = new Set();
const set2 = new Set();
for (const { apip, id } of data) {
  (apip === oneApip ? set1 : set2).add(id);
}
const uniq1 = [...set1];
const uniq2 = [...set2];
console.log(uniq1);
console.log(uniq2);
```

More generally, for any number of `apip`s, create an object indexed by `apip`, whose values are sets:

```js
var data=[{time:"1571965891.8420029",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"},{time:"1571971066.8283374",rssi:"30",id:"100",apip:"172.172.172.172.2"},{time:"1571965476.4821894",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.2"},{time:"1571965894.140705",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.2"},{time:"1571965893.1654441",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"},{time:"1571970952.7499905",rssi:"30",id:"9999999",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"},{time:"1571965888.1338017",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.2"},{time:"1571970925.342063",rssi:"30",id:"66666",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"},{time:"1571965890.158157",rssi:"30",id:"123456789",apip:"172.172.172.172.1"}];

const grouped = {};
for (const { apip, id } of data) {
  if (!grouped[apip]) {
    grouped[apip] = new Set();
  }
  grouped[apip].add(id);
}
const arrs = Object.entries(grouped)
  .map(([apip, set]) => [apip, [...set]]);
console.log(arrs);
```

Comment: wow that's some nice clean code right there, thank you thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const data = [{"time": "1571965891.8420029","rssi": "30","id": "123456789","apip": "172.172.172.172.1"}, {"time": "1571971066.8283374","rssi": "30","id": "100","apip": "172.172.172.172.2"}, {"time": "1571965476.4821894","rssi": "30","id": "123456789","apip": "172.172.172.172.2"}, {"time": "1571965894.140705","rssi": "30","id": "123456789","apip": "172.172.172.172.2"}, {"time": "1571965893.1654441","rssi": "30","id": "123456789","apip": "172.172.172.172.1"}, {"time": "1571970952.7499905","rssi": "30","id": "9999999","apip": "172.172.172.172.1"}, {"time": "1571965888.1338017","rssi": "30","id": "123456789","apip": "172.172.172.172.2"}, {"time": "1571970925.342063","rssi": "30","id": "66666","apip": "172.172.172.172.1"}, {"time": "1571965890.158157","rssi": "30","id": "123456789","apip": "172.172.172.172.1"}]

const sets = data.reduce(
    (a, { apip, id }, _, arr) => ((apip === arr[0].apip ? a.one : a.two).add(id), a),
    { 
      one: new Set(), 
      two: new Set() 
    }
  ),
  result = {
    uniqDataFromAP1: [...sets.one],
    uniqDataFromAP2: [...sets.two]
  }

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```